# Architecture/Design of PageObjects for Pages with hierarchy: menu-items/menu-sub-items/menu-sub-items-tabs

Tags: java, selenium, architecture, webdriver, pageobjects

I am developing a framework in Java for single-page webapp with selenium webdriver, using the following patterns: PageObject, SlowLoadableComponent (chain of responsibility), PageFactory, HaveExpectedControls (each page knows which elements it should contains and return them via .getExpectedControls)

So I create and use my pages like:

```
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver, "http://mywebapp.com");
mainPage MainPage = new MainPage(driver, loginPage, "password"); 
mainPage.get();  //this method checks whether page .isLoaded(), if not - calls its .load() method and finally assert it .isLoaded()
for (WebElement element: mainPage.getExpectedControls()) {
    assertTrue(element.isDisplayed);
}
```

***My current goal is: test all 'pathes' the user can do while surfing my webapp.***

Everything was easy until I get to pages, that are 'deeper' in my webapp hierarchy...

My pages can be represented as follows

```
------------
|Login Page|
------------
->
|------------------------------
|LogoutLink
|---------------------------------
|mode: _ standart _ expert|  __________________
|-------------------------| |SystemSettingsTab1|SystemSettingsTab2|SystemSettingsTab3
|*MainPage menu item      | |                   ----------------------------------------
|*SomeOther menu item     | |                                                           |
|...                      | |                                                           |
|*System menu item      >->
|** Settings sub item    >-> 
|...                      | |
|** OneMore sub item      | |
```

And here are some 'rules' for more explanation:

```
First you get Login Page
  Then (if loged in) you allways get 'MainPage menu item' (and 'standard' mode checked)
    You allways see (so can click only what you see):
      - only that sub-menu-items that are inside 'current' menu item page
      - only that sub-menu-items-tabs that are:
        - inside current sub-menu-item
        - is correspondent to the current mode ('expert' mode allows more tabs)
    Once clicked on any 'item' you allways get its first 'child item'
    Then whatever you do you can:
      - logout
      - switch to any 'item' which you can see (check correspondent section above):
        i.e.: 
        - switch to any other menu-item page by clicking on it
        - switch to any of sub-menu-items of the current menu-item:
            there is a special case for 'the first sub-menu-item':
              you can get it by:
                - clicking on its sub-menu-item link
                - on its parent menu-item 
        - switch to any of sub-menu-item-tabs of current sub-menu-item
            there is a special case for 'the first sub-menu-item-tab':
              you can get it by:
                - clicking on its sub-menu-item-tab link
                - on its parent sub-menu-item
                - on its parent menu-item
```

QUESTIONS:
**How to design:**

- **my class hierarchy for all pages?**
- **the way I can surf them in my tests?** (especially including special cases, where I can get some page via several links)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will be a simple and efficient solution,

1. Class for Main page with methods to navigate(or click) other menu items and logout.
2. Class for each menu item with methods for sub menu items, extend the Main page class